# Google Analytics for ios

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Why to use both set and send for creating custom dimesion for google analytics in iOS

```
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:value];
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:value forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the idea is to set (whatever it is that you are setting) and then send once - on a pageview level, thus reducing the amount of send requests.

You can set multiple things, and then send them all at once. See here a similar practice with Content Grouping:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167&vid=1-635769675688483808-1428855273

In Events you obliviously might send multiple times, as they occur.